# how to get a list of all top level pages

Tags: permalinks, pages

I am trying to figure out how to get a list of the permalinks for top-level pages only. My goal is to put them in a selection box on a form. I have spent a couple of hours searching here for an answer to no avail. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query_args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'parent'      => 0,
);

$pages = get_pages( $query_args );
```

Function `get_pages()` accepts parameter with `parent`. Keeping it 0 (zero) will give us first level pages. In the example `$pages` will contain the first level pages. Use loop for `$pages` and you can use it in option as you require.

Answer (score 0):

By the sounds of it, this should do what you're after. Just place it in wherever you want your list to output and you should be good to go.

```
<?php wp_list_pages('depth=1'); ?>
```

The depth argument being set to 1 is telling the function to only retrieve top level pages, but a lot more arguments are available. Take a look at the dev resources [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/).

Comment: Thank you for your response Ben. I read about the `wp_list_pages()` function. It says it returns the list in the html li format. I want to use the list to be parsed in a selection drop down in a form. I need to return a list of the permalinks themselve so I can parse them into the selection box.